# Why this loop does not terminate? (C language)

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

I am writing a code to save input in two array a and b.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int tell(int *a, int *b)
{
  /* I don't know what this function does */
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i, j, a[128], b[128];

  i = 0;
  while ((a[i] = getchar()) != 10) { // 10 represents enter key
    i++;
  }
  printf("here");

  j = 0;
  while ((b[j] = getchar()) != 10) {
    j++;
    printf("here2\n");
  }

  printf("here3");
  fflush(stdout);

  if (i < j) {
    printf("here4");
    printf("%d\n", tell(a, b));
  } else {
    printf("here4");
    printf("%d\n", tell(b, a));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

when i input :

```
hello
hi
```

output is:

```
here
here2 
here2
```

Why "here3" does not print?
The problem is not just printing here3 . I want to execute further code and it is not happening

Comment: Have you tried flushing the stdout?

Comment: i tried this i=0;
  while((a[i]=getchar())!=10){
   i++;
  }
  printf("here");
  fflush(stdout);
  j=0;
  while((b[j]=getchar())!='\n'){
   j++;
   printf("here2\n");
  }
  fflush(stdout);
  printf("here3"); 
but output is same

Comment: I updated your question so that the example code was compilable by itself and it works just fine.  here3 is printed.

Comment: @Sunil Try moving  `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("here3");`

Comment: it seems that further statements are executing but my tell function is creating the problem. So i will have a look at it.

Comment: actually there was an infinite loop in tell function which was causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `printf` function will flush the output buffer when it sees `\n`. Try:

```
printf("here3\n");
```

You could also use:

```
printf("here3");
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Actually my tell funcion had an infinite loop which was causing the illusion.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this.

Use `scanf()`,  or `fgets()` or `getline()` to read strings from the input.

Also, never write `10` when you mean `\n`, it's just not the same thing and the former is way worse. Also realize that `getchar()` can return `EOF`, which does not fit in a `char` and will wreak some havoc on your program.

That said, I can't spot an error that explains the behavior you're claiming. Re-write it anyway.

Comment: using '\n' also does not solve the problem

Comment: @SunilSharma No, but that's just because you happen to be on a system where `'\n'` equals 10. It's still very bad practice, which is why I wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

The second loop prints `here2` once for each character in the second string, so `here2`prints twice.

stdout is line buffered, which means that `here3` won't be visible until you either print a newline or `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: How does that explain seeing `here2` twice?

Comment: He entered `hi` as the second string. `hi` has 2 characters. Note that `here2`is printed **inside** the second loop.

Comment: after the flush, why is further code not executing

Comment: @Sunil It does for me. I tried it with gcc in Linux and it printed the final `here40`, just as expected.